# Haskell - Extract Maybe in Monad

Tags: haskell, monads

I am working on problem 9 of Project Euler, and I have a question about the best way to extract a maybe value inside another monad. The problem asks to find 'a', 'b', 'c' that satisfy:

- a^2 + b^2 = c^2
- a + b + c = 1000

I have written the following code that solves the problem:

```
problem9 :: (Integral a) => a -> [(a, a, a)]
problem9 n =
    do
        a <- [1..n]
        b <- [1..a]
        c <- fromJustM (findC a b)
        guard (a + b + c == n)
        return (a, b, c)
```

'c' can be computed analytically, but, since it may not exist, I return a maybe value.

```
findC :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> Maybe a
findC a b = ... (implementation) ...
```

To extract the maybe value inside the list monad, I have created the following function:

```
fromJustM :: (Monad m) => Maybe a -> m a
fromJustM (Just a) = return a
fromJustM Nothing = fail ""
```

It seems like this should be a common operation, so is there a standard library function that does this, or is there a more idiomatic way to do it?

Comment: Why not give `findC` a more polymorphic type (e.g. following the suggestions of the answer here `(Alternative f, Integral a) => a -> a -> f a`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fail` is not actually a monadic operation; it's only in the `Monad` type class because of historic accident / to hide some dirty error handling.

A more proper class for this is [`MonadPlus`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:MonadPlus), or rather its `Applicative` correspondent [`Alternative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative). `fail` translates to [`empty`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:empty). With that, your signature should in fact be

```
fromJustM' :: Alternative m => Maybe a -> m a
```

to which [Hoogle offers](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Alternative+m+%3D%3E+Maybe+a+-%3E+m+a)

```
asum :: (Foldable t, Alternative f) => t (f a) -> f a
```

Which fits the bill: `Maybe` is a `Foldable`.

```
        c <- asum $ pure <$> findC a b
```

Arguably, this is not in fact that readable.

---

You can actually achieve your goal much easier by writing

```
        Just c <- pure $ findC a b
```

This does again use the `fail` method: pattern-match failure in a `do` block calls it implicitly.